# MySQL: Looping Through Multiple Fields in an IN Clause

Tags: mysql, where-in

I have a universe that has one column where there are 3 types of id's. I know that I can use 3 separate OR clauses in my WHERE statement

```
WHERE isin IN(n) 
OR cusip IN(n) 
OR psedol IN(n)
```

but is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: 1 column with 3 types of id's, but you have 3 columns? Color me confused.

Comment: No, sorry. I have one column in a file that, using my example above, is comprised of cusips, isins, and psedols. However, in the table I wish to query to validate them I know that cusip, isin, and psedol are all separate fields. Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the order of your IN clause:

```
WHERE (n) IN (isin, cusip, psedol)
```

**EDIT:** The above would only work if (n) is only one column, for example, if it's "(SELECT x FROM y)".  If it's a list of things, reversing the order won't work and you have to keep it as you have it.

Another solution if (n) is a select is to move up your selectors into your joins.  Joins are more efficient than IN clauses.  For example, if n is "SELECT a FROM z", you could do something like this:

```
FROM y
INNER JOIN z ON z.ID = y.ID
INNER JOIN x ON x.ID = y.ID AND (x.isin = z.a OR x.cusip = z.a OR x.psedol = z.a)
```

... but that depends on the structure of your entire query, so you'd have to provide more information for me to be more specific.

Comment: @alecxe I was unaware that phrasing your answer in the form of a question is not allowed ... I watch too much Jeopardy, apparently ... but even phrased as a question, it provided an answer.

Comment: Sure, agreed, deleted my comment.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a little bit different from spsc_tech

```
FROM y
LEFT JOIN z ON ( z.ID = y.ID AND Z.ISIN = n)
LEFT JOIN x ON ( x.ID = y.ID AND X.CUSIP = n)
LEFT JOIN w ON ( w.ID = y.ID AND w.psedol = n)
```

if you put condition in ON clause in join, its much faster then in Where clause.
Hop this will work.